# Validate for number range using jquery.validate data annotations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

When constructing an input an ASP.NET MVC 3 view which uses jQuery.validate

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="text-box single-line" 
  id="ReserveQuantity" 
  name="ReserveQuantity" 
  data-val="true" 
  data-val-required="The Reserve Quantity field is required." 
  data-val-number="This value must be numeric"
>
```

this is markup that would be used for for a ReserveQuantity input. In addition to these parameters, what `data-` annotation should I use in order to make sure only a certain numeric range is acceptable here **without manual validation**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a built in data annotation for ranges, and it looks like this:

```
data-val-range="The field must be in range 0 to 104." 
data-val-range-min="0" 
data-val-range-max="104"
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/range#range

```
var minVal = 10, maxVal = 20;

$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        ReserveQuantity: {
            required: true,
            range: [ minVal, maxVal ]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How will this affect the current `data-` annotations?

Comment: I don't think it affects it them all.